# Insert HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**UPDATE**

I am trying to add a group which include textboxes and simple text in html using the onClick function

This is the html part of the button

```
    <div id="dynamicForm">
        <input type="submit" name="Add_fields" value="+" onclick="generateRow()">
    </div>
```

and the js

```
    <script>
function generateRow()
{
    document.getElementById('dynamicForm').innerHTML +='
                    <input name="dneven" type="text" width="30"/>
                        дневен
                    <select name="zapl">
                        <option selected="selected" value="3">-----</option> 
                        <option 1>платен</option>
                        <option 2>неплатен</option>
                    </select>
                        отпуск от  
                    <select name="god">
                        <option selected="selected" value="11">---</option>
    <option 1>2011</option>
    <option 2>2012</option>
                    </select>г.
                ';
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't do anything. Where is my mistake and also how can I make the button to dissapear after it is pressed once? I'll appreciate all your help thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does innerHTML comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error here because you your quotes.

```
innerHTML+="<input name="name" type="text" width="30"/> some text <input name="name" type="text" width="30"/>";
```

Here is a syntactically correct version. Note the string is in single quotes, which means the double quoted HTML attributes won't accidentally terminate the string.

```
innerHTML+='<input name="name" type="text" width="30"/> some text <input name="name" type="text" width="30"/>';
```

If you are still stuck, you may need to give us a little more code - have you used `innerHTML` as a short-hand to the actual innerHTML of an element or is it a variable declared somewhere?

**Update**

> I haven't declared innerHTML anywhere

If you want to add your string of HTML to an element, you'll need to use:

```
document.getElementById('myElementId').innerHTML += 'html string';
```

As just putting

```
innerHTML += 'html string';
```

Creates an implicit global variable (and errors because you are trying to append to something that doesn't yet exist).

**Update**

> I want to insert the HTML right after the button

HTML:

```
<div id="dynamicForm">
    <input type="submit" name="Add_fields" value="+" onclick="generateRow()">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function generateRow() {
    document.getElementById('dynamicForm').innerHTML += '<input name="name" type="text" width="30"/> some text <input name="name" type="text" width="30"/>';
}
```

Later on, you might want to get into creating elements and appending them to the DOM without using strings and adding the event handlers in script rather than HTML - but this should get you started.

**Update**

You can't have line-breaks in your string in JavaScript, so you need either one line, or lots of appends. [Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uLKpB).

Comment: I haven't declared innerHTML anywhere. I tried with the single quotes but the button still doesn't work

Comment: But where do you want to insert the HTML? Get the parent element via `document.getElementById()` or for example with `this.parentNode.innerHTML` (that's the parent node of the triggering element - here the input field).

Comment: Can i use the buttons id and its html to be something like this
<input type="submit" name="Add_fields" value="+" onclick="generateRow()" id="add"> and then the js 
document.getElementByID('add').innerHTML += 'html string';

Comment: @w4kv I have added an example, using a `div` element to wrap the dynamic form.

Comment: It still doesn't do anything I updated my post with more from the part i want to inser if there is the problem

Comment: You can't have line-breaks in your string in JavaScript, so you need either one line, or lots of appends. Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/uLKpB/

Comment: @Sohnee thanks for you help and one last question how can i make the button to dissapear after it is used once?

Answer (score 1):

User [jnerator](http://jnerator.com).

1. Create jtag:

   ```
   var jtag = $j.tagArray([
       $j.inputText({ name: 'dneven', width: 30 }),
       'дневен',
       $j.select([
           $j.option({ selected: 'selected', value: '3', child: '------' }),
           $j.option({ value: '1', child: 'платен' }),
           $j.option({ value: '2', child: 'неплатен' })
       ]),
       'отпуск от ',
       $j.select({
           name: 'god',
           child: [
               $j.option({ selected: 'selected', value: '11', child: '------' }),
               $j.option({ value: '1', child: '2011' }),
               $j.option({ value: '2', child: '2012' })
           ]
       })
   ]);
   ```
2. Get html code

   ```
   var htmlCode = jtag.html();
   // jtag.html() returns:
   // <input name="dneven" width="30" type="text" ></input>дневен<select><option selected="selected" value="3" >------</option><option value="1" >платен</option><option value="2" >неплатен</option></select>отпуск от <select name="god" ><option selected="selected" value="11" >------</option><option value="1" >2011</option><option value="2" >2012</option></select>
   ```
3. Insert HTML Code into existing tag

   ```
   document.getElementById('dynamicForm').innerHTML += htmlCode;
   ```